# Is the evaluation of a function call's "this" in an unspecified order relative to the parameters?

Tags: c++, parameter-passing, this

It's widely-known (though not widely enough >.<) that C and C++ don't specify the order in which parameters to a function are evaluated.  That is, the two `puts()`s below can occur in either order, as an arbitrary compiler choice:

```
#include <cstdio>

int Function1() {
    std::puts("Function1");
    return 1;
}

int Function2() {
    std::puts("Function2");
    return 2;
}

int Add(int x, int y) {
    return x + y;
}

int main() {
    return Add(Function1(), Function2());
}
```

However, does this also apply to the evaluation of `this` on the left side of the `.`, `.*`, `->` or `->*` operators?  In other words, is the order of the `puts()`'s below *also* unspecified?

```
#include <cstdio>

struct Struct {
    Struct() { std::puts("Struct::Struct"); }
    int Member(int x) const { return x * 2; }
};

int Function() {
    std::puts("Function");
    return 14;
}

int main() {
    return Struct().Member(Function());
}
```

Comment: According to http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order, the order is _unspecified_ in both cases.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Struct().Member(Function())
```

This is a function call where the *postfix-expression* is `Struct().Member` and the argument is `Function()`. In general, in a function call, the evaluation of the *postfix-expression* is unsequenced with respect to the evaluation of arguments.

Therefore the order of the `puts` calls is indeed unspecified.

It's completely irrelevant that the function is a non-static member function.